# GGanimate: Visualize animal daily movement with elevation background

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, gganimate

***Background:*** I have a GPS tracking dataset of an animal which only moves during the day. The dataset consists out of manual tracking follows. So there are follows for some days where the tracking of the animal is recorded with **manualDatetime**, **E** (easting), **N** (northing), the corresponding **trackpoint_ID** in the follow (sequence over day) and the **follow_ID** itself, as well as a unique **identification** for every GPS-Point. I would like to visualise the whole movement of this animal, all follows of all days as a one day animation.

***Target:*** The result would be that I see the movement of all follows over daytime (maybe there are some patterns, probably not). I successfully used gganimate and transition_reveal over the **manualDatetime** stamp to visualise the animal trajectories. But now comes the tricky part. I would like to use some topographic landmarks as background. Specifically a digital terrain model and a river polygon. But if I include any layer like geom_raster or geom_sf the animation fails. Probably because these layers don't have the columns indicating the transition_reveal argument (time). How could I achieve an animation with the movement visualisation of the trajectory and the static raster as a background? So how should I alter the code below that I can include the uncommented two lines (geom_raster and geom_sf as static background)?

Below there is a subset of the whole dataset and code. Because I do many of these plots for alot of animals. But I thought its also better to have a real chunk of dataset. The code and the datasets are available in the google drive below.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xcgt0EwHNhanoT9I5kEhvs8V5phUEuH6?usp=sharing

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

# river polygon
SUAQ_river_sf_wgs<- st_read(dsn="data/external/GeodataIndonesia/Wasser/fluss_50k_perimetergross.shp")
SUAQ_river_sf_loc <- st_transform(SUAQ_river_sf_wgs,crs = 23847) # transform to local coordinate system

# digital elevation model
SUAQ_dem <- raster(x = "data/external/DEM_50m.tif")
SUAQ_dem_spdf <- as(SUAQ_dem, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
SUAQ_dem_df <- as.data.frame(SUAQ_dem_spdf)
colnames(SUAQ_dem_df) <- c("value", "E", "N")

# tracking dataset
data<- read_csv("/Users/stefgr/Nextcloud/UZH/12_Semester/20200313_Masterthesis/R/output/animations/stackoverflow/data.csv")

# animation
ggplot(data) +
  #geom_tile(data=SUAQ_dem_df, aes(x=E1,y=N1,fill=value))+# ggplot works but the animation doesn't work if included
  #scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high="black")+ # color elevation map

  #geom_sf(data=SUAQ_river_sf_loc, fill="cadetblue3",lwd = 0)+# ggplot works but the animation doesn't work if included
  geom_path(data=data,aes(x = E,y = N,group= follow, colour= as.factor(follow)))+
  geom_point(
    size = 1,
    stroke = 0,
    shape = 16,
    mapping = aes(
      x = E,y = N,group=identification
    ),
    alpha = 1,
    na.rm = TRUE,
    show.legend = FALSE
  )+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  guides(colour= guide_legend(title = "Movement follows"))+
  
  # Here comes the gganimate specific bits:
  #labs(title = 'Time: {hour(hms::as_hms(frame_along))}:{minute(hms::as_hms(frame_along))}', x = 'E', y = 'N')+
  transition_reveal(hms::as_hms(round_date(manualDatetime, unit = "minute")),keep_last = TRUE)
```

Without the raster or the sf (lines are commented in code above) part the ggplot and the animation works (see below):

[image: ggplot without elevation model and river in background]

The intended ggplot (without the animation part):
[image: Intended ggplot (missing the animation :( )]

Quick side note: I also succeeded to show the geom_tiles if I added a random manualDatetime from the main data to the DEM file. But then the tiles appeared and dissapeared for the specific manualDatetimes. See below additional code and output below:

```
timestamps_fromdata<- data[order(data$manualDatetime , decreasing = FALSE ),] %>% dplyr::select(manualDatetime)
timestamps_fromdata<- dplyr::pull(timestamps_fromdata,manualDatetime)
timestamps_fromdata<- rep(timestamps_fromdata, times = 13)
SUAQ_dem_df <- SUAQ_dem_df %>% cbind(timestamps_fromdata[1:nrow(SUAQ_dem_df)])
colnames(SUAQ_dem_df) <- c("value", "E1", "N1","manualDatetime")
```

Part of the gif (whole gif was too big)
[image]

*R-info:

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

Running under: macOS  10.16



Packages:

sf_0.9-6

gganimate_1.0.5

tidyverse_1.3.0

raster_3.1-5

ggplot2_3.3.2*

Comment: just a guess, but try adding `coord_sf(xlim = c(...), ylim = c(...))` so it doesn't move the background as the points move

Comment: the "movement" in the background of the third plot in the comment is just an artefact because I assigned the times as a vector to the raster data frame. The animation therefore let appear and disappear these "tile-pixels" according to the randomly assigned time from the main dataset. Its that what you meant right? Thanks anyway!